# SciPy pdist diagonal is zero with custom metric function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a problem with calculating pairwise similarities using pdist from SciPy.

This is my similarity function

```
>>>def custom_metric(p1,p2):       
       '''Calculate the similarity of two vectors
       For vectors [10, 20, 30] and [5, 10, 15], the results is 0.5 similarity
       '''

       mins = np.sum(np.minimum(p1,p2))
       maxes = np.sum(np.maximum(p1,p2))
       return mins/maxes
```

Here is a sample data​ (`dum` for dummy)

```
>>> dum = pd.DataFrame([[10,20,30,40],
                       [10,20,30,40],
                       [5, 10,15,20],
                       [5,0,0,0]],
                     index=['product_{}'.format(i) for i in range(1,5)],
                     columns=['ingredient_{}'.format(i) for i in range(1,5)])
>>> dum.head()
                  ingredient_1  ingredient_2    ingredient_3    ingredient_4
       product_1        10          20              30              40
       product_2        10          20              30              40
       product_3        5           10              15              20
       product_4        5           0               0               0
```

If I calculate the similarity manually it works fine.

```
>>> custom_metric(dum.ix['product_2'],dum.ix['product_3'])
... 0.5

>>> custom_metric(dum.ix['product_2'],dum.ix['product_2'])
... 1.0
```

However using pdist yields this:

```
>>> similarities = pd.DataFrame(squareform(pdist(dum, custom_metric)), index=dum.index, columns=dum.index); similarities

              product_1     product_2   product_3   product_4
   product_1    0.00        1.00        0.5           0.05
   product_2    1.00        0.00        0.5           0.05
   product_3    0.50        0.50        0.0           0.10
   product_4    0.05        0.05        0.1           0.00
```

Which is OK except for the diagonal which should be 1.

Now I understand the fact, that `pdist` is used to calculate distances and distance of "a thing" with itself is `0`, but I am surprised it still works this way even with custom function. I even checked the [source for pdist](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.18.1/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L978-L1397) but found no manual handling of the diagonal elements.

Is it ok if I do

```
>>> np.eye(similarities.shape[0]) + similarities
```

to add 1's to the diagonal, or will it mess things up?

Comment: The "manual handling" is here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L1234-L1238;  `pdist` never calls your function with the same vector, because it "knows" that the distance must be 0.

Comment: Silly me. Thank you! So Adding 1 to the diagonal will be fine.

Comment: Yes, that should be fine.  (Actually, it is `squareform` that is putting the zeros in the diagonal; `pdist` just computes one side of the distance matrix and returns it in "condensed" form.)